# Run function and keep loop running c++

Tags: c++

How to run a function within loop and still keep loop running without waiting when the function2 completes?

```
int main(){
 function1();
}

function1(){
   while(1){
      function2();   }
}

function2(){
   //some task that needs to do independently while, While loop runs
}
```

Comment: You need multiple threads.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html

Comment: So you want to run `function1()` and `function2()` at the same time?

Comment: Do you realize that if you don't wait for `function2()`, you're going to get *a lot* of instances of it running simultaneously.

Comment: Are you trying to create o fork bomb? :-D

Comment: Function2 will be called on a  if statement. (forgot to add it), so keep ya all your shorts on lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch `function2` async:

```
#include <future>
void function1(){
   while(1){
      std::async(std::launch::async, function2);   
   }
}
```

Do note that this will generate a lot of instances that all call `function2()`, you should probably throttle that.

Comment: But, will this block the main thread forever since you didn't assign the result of `std::async` to the `std::future` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Spawn a new thread with function2 and then start them in function 1 in the loop where you previously called it. It should compile but it will spawn infinite threads and something will go wrong so be careful. Sounds like threading is your solution though